# Prevent failed Insert from claiming next Identity value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

When an `INSERT` fails into a table with an auto incremented identity field, the identity is still incremented, thus producing gaps in the identity sequence.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please ignore exact numerical values of identity columns. They only exist to identify rows. If you need them to conform to a rule, you need a non-identity field, calculated manually on each insert.

Comment: Isn't this what transactions are for?

Comment: @GSerg - In the table I'm working with these IDs serve as the sole unique identifier for a record for non-technical users.  I realize having gaps means nothing in reality, they don't.  I am just wondering if this is preventable, not whether the gap should have significance or not.

Comment: @Jim - Transactions do not change this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is to reseed the table or build your own identity generator

example

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT IDENTITY, bla INT)

INSERT test VALUES(1)
INSERT test VALUES('b') --fails


DBCC CHECKIDENT(test,RESEED,1) --RESEED table
INSERT test VALUES(1)
SELECT * FROM test

DROP TABLE test
```

On a busy table you might get inserts after that and the reseed won't be correct anymore
But why do you need this? Who cares if there are gaps

Comment: Thanks for at least attempting to answer the question if its preventable.  I realize it shouldn't matter but as these are visible to end users who don't understand the gaps, I was just wondering if I could easily prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Random idea from left field: Identify what's actually causing the failed inserts and validate against *that*, while of course realizing that due to the validations and the inserts not being atomic, you may still get failures (for things such as duplicates in unique fields).

It seems the identity gap is the *symptom*, the failure is the *illness*. Treat the illness.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want the key to have no meaning behind it other than identifying the record.  That means if there are gaps in the numbering, it should not matter.  If you are inserting a record into another related table, you can always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in your stored proc/trigger, etc.

Comment: Not trying to argue that there should be meaning to these IDs but they do serve as the sole unique identifier for external users (who then read into the gaps as something larger).  I personally do not care if there are gaps but am merely asking if I can avoid it, how would I?

Comment: GSerg is right in the comments to your question.  If that is your requirement, you would need to store that off in a different field that has a unique constraint on it, and calculate the value manually on insert.